# Fill empty vertical space with a single diagonal line

Tags: spacing, rules

I'm currently writing a document with the `book` class.

At the end of every part, I have a box where I put my name and I can sign. This box fills the whole horizontal space but is only a couple of lines tall.

I want to position this box at the end of the page, and I want the empty space that is left above it 'striked through' with a line or maybe crossed out with two lines. (This is a legally binding document so you don't want to leave any whitespace above your signature!)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}


\begin{document}

\def\a{One two three four five six seven eight nine ten. }
\def\b{\a\a Red yellow blue green. \a\par}
\def\c{\b\b\a\a\b\b\b\a\a\b}

\c
\noindent\tikzmark{a}\hfill\tikzmark{b}\par
\vfill
\noindent\tikzmark{aa}\hfill\tikzmark{bb}\par
\noindent
\framebox[\textwidth][l]{sig:}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {\draw[<->,] (a) to (bb);}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {\draw[<->,] (b) to (aa);}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** the lines will appear on the second run as they use measurements taken the previous time the document was processed, if you edit the document make sure to latex it twice to get the end points in the correct place.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina But I was so proud of myself having made my first tikz answer, I thought I'd use two:-)